# Apache Solr support for ORC file format

Tags: hadoop, solr, hive, orc

I have a bunch of tables in Hive, stored as ORC. I want to index their data in a SolrCloud collection.

Is there any support for indexing data stored in ORC format in Solr?
I've googled around but nothing came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want *SolR* to read data from a specific Hive file format.

You might look at the problem the other way i.e. use *Hive* to write data *to SolR* -- and thus let Hive take care of the complexity of the actual input file format (whether ORC, Parquet, AVRO, whatever -- even HBase data files).

In the [LucidWorks GitHub repo](https://github.com/lucidworks) you will find a project labeled **hive-solr**. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'll accept Samson's answer.

Anyway, I'm not fully satisfied about this solution. In fact, now I still need to create an external table manually declaring all fields in the original table. In terms of operations, it is not different from creating a new table (stored ad textfile) starting from the original one, indexing the new text files and finally dropping them (of course, this may be a problem for very large tables, which is not my case).

Being ORC a self-describing format, it would be great for Solr to read both field names and data directly from the compressed files.

Comment: Well, the ORC project now ships a "core java" API _(since V1.1 - june 2016)_ => cf. intro at https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html and JavaDoc at https://orc.apache.org/api/orc-core/index.html?org/apache/orc/Reader.html => you may try a bit of DIY development..